# No Class found Exception - org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase

Tags: java, woocommerce, java-web-start, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to consume Woo Commerce Rest API using Java program. I am getting error given below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase

at com.icoderman.woocommerce.WooCommerceAPI.<init>(WooCommerceAPI.java:21)
at testWooCommerseAPI.main(testWooCommerseAPI.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Java code

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

    OAuthConfig config = new OAuthConfig("url", 
    "key", 
    "secret code");

    WooCommerce wooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI(config, ApiVersionType.V2);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("per_page","100");
    params.put("offset","0");
    List products = wooCommerce.getAll(EndpointBaseType.PRODUCTS.getValue(), 
    params);
}
```

Dependency used

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.icoderman</groupId>
    <artifactId>wc-api-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: call `mvn dependency:tree` from where your project is and see whether apache http client is listed as dependency. If not, you have to add it explicitly to your pom.

Comment: worth posting the answer how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Client dependency need to add to solve the above problem.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```